# How to use Event::queue in laravel?

Tags: events, laravel, queue

I've read a lot about `Event::queue` but I just cant get my head around it, so i have something like:

```
Event::listen('send_notification');
```

and in the controller I use

```
Event::fire('send_notification');
```

But because this takes sometime before sending the user to somewhere else, I instead want to use

```
Event::queue('send_notification');
```

To fire the event *after* the user has been redirected, but I don't know how.

(In the `app/config/app.php` i have the `queue driver` set to `sync`)

**EDIT:**

a small note about firing the event ,u can do all ur work just like normal ,and add all the `Event::flush()` as a filter ,then just call that filter through `->after()` or `afterFilter()`.

Comment: Queued events have nothing to do with the queue driver. `Event::queue` is just to "prepare" a event and fire it late *that request* using [`flush()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events#queued-events)

Comment: @lukasgeiter thanks for that ,i was just lost between both ,but now lets say i have more than one event ,should i put them into the `flush()` as an array or else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me make something clear. `Event::queue` has nothing to do with the `Queue` facade and the query driver in the config. It won't enable you to fire the event after the request has happened.

But you can delay the firing of an event and therefore "prepare" it.

The usage is pretty basic. Obviously you need one or many `Event::listen` (well it works without them but makes no sense at all)

```
Event::listen('send_notification', function($text){
    // send notification
});
```

Now we queue the event:

```
Event::queue('send_notification', array('Hello World'));
```

And finally, fire it by calling `flush`

```
Event::flush('send_notification');
```

---

In your comment you asked about flushing multiple events at once. Unfortunately that's not really possible. You have to call `flush()` multiple times

```
Event::flush('send_notification');
Event::flush('foo');
Event::flush('bar');
```

If you have a lot of events to flush you might need to think about your architecture and if it's possible to combine some of those into one event with multiple listeners.

#### Flushing the Event after redirect

`Event::queue` can't be used to fire an event after the request lifecycle has ended. You have to use ["real" queues](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) for that.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for ,also where do u usually place the `Event::flush()` code ? ,i was thinking about using it after the `return Redirect::back();` but u cant execute anything after the `return` so ?

Comment: thanx,it works now , but it takes the same time the usual `Event::fire` takes.

Comment: Too bad. Then you'll have to use "real" queues as I've written above. I'll also remove the code example since it doesn't help at all...

Comment: okey ,one last question ,how to check if an event was queued ? consider somthing like this `($this->getNotified() == true) ? Event::queue('update_subscribe') : Event::queue('remove_subscribe');`

Comment: I don't think you can do that and I don't think you should need to.  Note that you can call `flush()` regardless if the event has been queued or not (if not it will just do nothing)

Comment: great ,thanx again for all ur help :).